# addEventListener to an array of buttons using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, addeventlistener

I am trying to made a series of buttons (in the div included in the html) give an alert when clicked. For that I am using addEventListener. If I just make a list (as showed belowed commented) the result is fine. I try to make the code DRY by using a for loop but it returns me only that "clicked 8" no matter what I press. As far as I understand the flow should start by testing i=0 and continue with the others the same way as with the entire list. So if I press the button[0] I should get "clicked 1" and that's all because the other conditions are false.
Thanks in advance.

```js
// document.querySelectorAll("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 1")});
// document.querySelectorAll("button")[1].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 2")});
// document.querySelectorAll("button")[2].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 3")});
// document.querySelectorAll("button")[3].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 4")});
// document.querySelectorAll("button")[4].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 5")});
// document.querySelectorAll("button")[5].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 6")});
// document.querySelectorAll("button")[6].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 7")});

for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {
document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked " + (i+1))});
}
```

```html
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue comes from the behavior of using `var` keyword to define variable.

In ES6 there were introduced `let` and `const` keywords. If you use them you will stop facing issues of `var` hoisting and scope.

So, you can add a `let` keyword to your `i` declaration like this:

```js
for (let i=0; i<=6; i++) {
  //the rest of the code
}
```

You can read more in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).

#### Short summary of the linked question in your issue

When you write `i = 0` you are defining the `i` property in the `window` object. Then in loop you are incrementing this value.
When using `i` in passed function, javascript is getting the value from `window` object.

On the other hand, `let` keyword defines the scope of variable to the scope of your loop, so passed function always contains copy of value, when the function was passed.

Comment: That was very useful my namesake. It would've taken me a while till I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

you can dry your code in this way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((el, i) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => alert(`clicked ${i+1}`))
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the function keeps track of the value of I even after the loop. Add another variable and bind it to the alert

```js
    // document.querySelectorAll("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 1")});
    // document.querySelectorAll("button")[1].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 2")});
    // document.querySelectorAll("button")[2].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 3")});
    // document.querySelectorAll("button")[3].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 4")});
    // document.querySelectorAll("button")[4].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 5")});
    // document.querySelectorAll("button")[5].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 6")});
    // document.querySelectorAll("button")[6].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked 7")});

    for(var i=0;i<7; i++) {
    let out = i+1
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked " + (out))});
    }
```

```html
      <div class="set">
        <button class="w drum">w</button>
        <button class="a drum">a</button>
        <button class="s drum">s</button>
        <button class="d drum">d</button>
        <button class="j drum">j</button>
        <button class="k drum">k</button>
        <button class="l drum">l</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching listeners to all the buttons you might take advantage of [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) which allows you to add *one* listener to the parent element (`.set` in this case), and catch events from the buttons as they "bubble up" the DOM.

In this example I'm logging the text content of the buttons when they are clicked.

```js
// Cache the parent element and add a listener
const set = document.querySelector('.set');
set.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Extract the nodeName and textContent from
  // the clicked element
  const { nodeName, textContent } = e.target;

  // If it's a button, log the text
  if (nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    console.log(textContent);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)