# Javascript: Setting buttons linked to functions dynamically (with dynamic parameters)

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage which I'm writing an extension for which detects 1 or more table/div sections and I want to insert a button into each to then call a function and pass in dynamic parameters to another function. The problem I'm running into is the dynamic values are always the last in the loop even though the button IDs appear correct in the page source (dynamic). Simplified code extract below:

```
for (var milestone_id in all_milestones) {
    milestone = all_milestones[milestone_id];
    button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.setAttribute("id", "callout_" + milestone_id);
    button.setAttribute("style", "float: right");
    button.value = "Create/Edit Details";
    button.onclick = function() {open_browser(award_id, milestone_id, milestone["date"], env)};
    milestone["class"].appendChild(button);
}
```

Current behaviour - buttons are successfully injected in with unique IDs (callout_{milestone_id}) but when invoking the function (open_browser) the milestone_id is static // the last value of milestone in the array.

Desired behaviour - as above but ensuring the correct dynamic values are sent through as per the time that the button is injected into the form.

Comment: How do you insert the buttons?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include this -> milestone["class"].appendChild(button); The milestone["class"] is just the class / div that the button resides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `for...in` loop in combination with `var` for the loop variable. This makes it a global variable and it is overwritten each iteration and not local to the loop. You cannot use that in a closure kind of way like this. Use `let` or `const` for the loop variable instead.

```
for (let milestone_id in all_milestones) {
  ...
}
```

See [this MDN-Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for more information on `for...in`

See [this MDN-Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) for more information on `var`

See [this MDN-Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for more information on `const`

See [this MDN-Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for more information on `let`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, just tried seems to be same behaviour. I was looking for the deepcopy python equivalent in javascript as I know the problem just not the method to prevent it :)

Comment: try an arrow/lambda function maybe instead of an anonymous one: ``()=>{}`` and try ``addEventListener('click', ()=>{...})``

Comment: Also on a sidenote. Your code style is a bit inconsistent. You are using ``setAttribute`` only for ``id`` and ``style`` but not for ``type``, ``value`` and ``onclick``. And you are using snake_case, in js better stick to camelCasing

Comment: Thanks I've tried this notation also without success ->         button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            open_browser(award_id, milestone_id, milestone["date"], env);
        });  Noted RE style I do very little JS and will tidy it up

Comment: ah man maybe I was wrong. You are using for...in combined with var which makes it a global variable. Use ``let`` instead! Sorry for the trouble! I updated my answer...

Comment: another suggestion: never use ``var`` again, always use ``const`` or ``let`` instead. ``var`` was never a good idea to begin with in JS

Comment: Excellent thanks for the tip! By good chance I came across this thread which also articulates the reasoning! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749646/addeventlistener-to-an-array-of-buttons-using-a-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Add the different variables (the variables that you used as parameters for the function) as either data-* attributes (like the `button.dataset.milestone_id` in the example) or as properties (like the `button.award_id` in the example) on the button. If it is a number or a string you can just use the data-* attribute. If the variable is an object or an element (like a reference to a div or table) you can add it as a property.

And then in the click event callback function you get the button by `e.target` and then you can access either standard attributes, data-* attributes or properties.

```js
const all_milestones = [1, 2, 3];

const open_browser = e => {
  let button = e.target;
  console.log(button.id, button.dataset.milestone_id, button.award_id);
};

for (var milestone_id in all_milestones) {
  let milestone = all_milestones[milestone_id];
  button = document.createElement("button");
  button.type = "button";
  button.id = "callout_" + milestone_id;
  button.dataset.milestone_id = milestone_id; // data-* attribute
  button.award_id = 'some award id'; // property on button
  button.dataset.milestone_date = 'some date';
  button.dataset.env = 'env';
  button.textContent = "Create/Edit Details";
  button.addEventListener('click', open_browser);
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```